# Test if a sentence is matching a text declaration using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test if a sentence like `type var1,var2,var3` is matching a text declaration or not.

So, I used the following code :

```js
var text = "int a1,a2,a3",
     reg = /int ((([a-z_A-Z]+[0-9]*),)+)$/g;

if (reg.test(text)) console.log(true);
else console.log(false)
```

The problem is that this regular expression returns false on text that is supposed to be true.

Could someone help me find a good regular expression matching expressions as in the example above?

Comment: What about `int a,b,c,`, should it be true? Also, your regex does not allow `a2b2`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: int a,b,c, should be false

I have found a good solution 

/int ([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*(,([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*))*)$/g.test(str)

Comment: I see, so you accepted an answer that does not answer your question. There is also an issue with the modifier you are using with `RegExp#test()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: because other answers doesn't work for me and that answer was the best

Comment: You can answer yourself, BTW.

Comment: you just need learn how to ask... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `?` after the comma `,`.

This token `?` matches between zero and one.

Notice that the last number in your text `a3` does not have `,` afterward.

```
int ((([a-z_A-Z]+[0-9]*),?)+)$
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of mistekes.

1. As you wrote, the last coma is required at the end of the line.
2. I suppose you also want to match `int abc123` as correct string, so you need to include letter to other characters
3. Avoid using capturing groups for just testing strings.

---

```
const str = 'int a1,a2,a3';
const regex = /int (?:[a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_])*(?:\,|$))+/g

console.log(regex.test(str));
```